# Exporting/importing via FFI vs. using the FFI wrapper

Tags: haskell, function-pointers, ffi

I inherited a code base using the following idiom, which exports and then reimports a function via the FFI:

```
foreign export ccall someHaskellFn :: a -> IO b
foreign import ccall "&someHaskellFn"
  someHaskellFn_addr :: FunPtr (a -> IO b)
```

Neither the Haskell function `someHaskellFn`, nor the exported function is ever used; only `someHaskellFn_addr` is required, and is always used in an IO context:

```
-- frob :: FunPtr (a -> IO b) -> IO ()
frob someHaskellFn_addr
```

I'm wondering whether this has any advantages over using a *wrapper* function:

```
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  mkWrapper :: (a -> IO b) -> IO (FunPtr (a -> IO b))

-- Function pointer to someHaskellFn, never freed
someHaskellFnPtr = mkWrapper someHaskellFn
frob =<< someHaskellFnPtr
```

---

The documentation for Foreign.Ptr mentions these two methods to create a value of type `FunPtr a`:

> A value of type FunPtr a may be a pointer to a foreign function,
>   either returned by another foreign function or imported with a a
>   static address import like
>
> ```
> foreign import ccall "stdlib.h &free"
>   p_free :: FunPtr (Ptr a -> IO ())
> ```
>
> or a pointer to a Haskell function created using a wrapper stub
>   declared to produce a FunPtr of the correct type.

It also says

> Calls to *wrapper* stubs […] allocate storage, which should be released with freeHaskellFunPtr when no longer required.

My understanding is that the *wrapper* using code behaves indentical (on the Haskell side) to the export/import variant; is this correct? Are there any finer details about foreign function imports and exports which I am missing?

Comment: When one creates a wrapper function, it is implied that arbitrary function pointers of that signature may be needed. The style here let’s you know exactly which functions might be passed to C. I don’t know a great deal about the Haskell ffi. Perhaps this style predates the introduction of wrapper functions.

Comment: Wrappers can also provide pointer to closures. A function `a -> IO b` in Haskell can be crafted at runtime, unlike in C. E.g. `do x <- readLn ; w <- mkWrapper (\y -> print (x+y)) ; use w` has to build a pointer to a closure containing the value of `x`. Every time a wrapper is created, a new closure will be allocated, so that they can refer to different values of `x`. If you don't need that flexibility, but only want a pointer to a fixed function, the export/import mechanism seems more primitive.

Comment: I have never seen the first style of exporting a Haskell function just to import a function pointer to that function. I cannot find it in any documentation (which, if it existed there, may indicate why one would use one style over the other). The Haskell FFI is somewhat fragile, so I wouldn't even assume that it works without testing it (even with testing, I still wouldn't think it 'works' - just like undefined behaviour in C can produce the correct answer 'sometimes').

Comment: Another thought: the export-import method here does not require any run time allocation of functions which means there is never a process of writing to executable memory or writing to memory and then changing it to executable. Perhaps some very strict security policies would not be happy with using a wrapper for this reason. Also this way you’ll probably get some debugging symbols for these functions so e.g. gdb could tell you which function you are about to call from C. Finally if you use wrapper functions then you need to find somewhere in your program to put the `IO` action of wrapping.